# Implementation of the search field by data database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-web-start

I have a database with tables: *airline*, *flights* (many-to-one airline).

I'm trying to do a flight search based on flight number.

Where is get and set for each field in the database table?

```
public List<Flight> findFlightsByAircompany(int aircompany_id) throws DBException {
        List<Flight> list = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_FLIGHT_BY_AIRCOMPANY);
            pstmt.setInt(1, aircompany_id);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(getFlight(rs));
            }
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            rollback(con);
            throw new DBException("Cannot find flight by aircompany id", e);
        } finally {
            close(con, pstmt, rs);

        }
        return list;
    }

    public List<Flight> findFlightByNumber(String number) throws DBException{
        List<Flight> list = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_FLIGHT_BY_NUMBER);
            pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(number));
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(getFlight(rs));
            }
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            rollback(con);
            throw new DBException("Cannot find flight by number", e);
        } finally {
            close(con, pstmt, rs);

        }
        return list;
    }

private Flight getFlight(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DBException {
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
        flight.setName(rs.getString(NAME));
        flight.setStartPoint(rs.getString("STARTPOINT"));
        flight.setEndPoint(rs.getString("ENDPOINT"));
        flight.setNumber(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        flight.setDepartureTime(rs.getInt("DEPARTURE_TIME"));
        flight.setAircompanyId(rs.getInt("AIRCOMPANY_ID"));
        return flight;
    }
```

**SQL requests**

```
private static final String GET_FLIGHT_BY_AIRCOMPANY = "SELECT * from flight where AIRCOMPANY_ID=?";    
private static final String GET_FLIGHT_BY_NUMBER = "SELECT * from flight where number=?";
```

After that I try to get the attribute

```
int aircompany = -1;

    if (session.getAttribute(AIRCOMOANY) != null) {
                aircompany = (Integer) session.getAttribute(AIRCOMOANY);
            }

            if (request.getParameter(AIRCOMOANY) != null) {
                aircompany = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(AIRCOMOANY));
            }
            System.out.println(aircompany);

            String sort = request.getParameter("sort");

            List<Flight> flight = db.findFlightsByAircompany(aircompany);;

            if ("name".equals(sort)) {
                Collections.sort(flight, new Comparators.CompareByName());
            } else if ("number".equals(sort)) {
                Collections.sort(flight, new Comparators.CompareByNumber());
            }
            String search = request.getParameter("search");
            if ("number".equals(search)){
                System.out.println("fewfw");
                flight = db.findFlightByNumber(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("number"))); //maybe it's wrong
            }
```

How to correctly make a call to "number" field and later use on JSP page?

```
<div align="center">
    <form action="controller" method="post">
        <fmt:message key="sort_by"/> <select name="sort">
        <option value="name"><fmt:message key="admin_jsp.aircompany_name"/></option>
        <option value="number"><fmt:message key="number"/></option>
    </select> <input type="hidden" name="command" value="getFlights"> <input
            type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="sort"/>">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="controller" method="post">
        <option value ="number"><fmt:message key="number"/></option><input type="text" name="search" value ="">
        <input type ="hidden" name ="command" value ="getFlights"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

</div>
```

A few screenshots of my application.

- On the first screen I choose the airline, then I get the list of flights.

  [image: App screenshot]
- On the second I have to search by flight number. For clarity in my classes I gave an example of how I do the sorting and it works correctly, but with the search I have a problem. I need to enter the flight number in the field and only receive it.

  [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the session attribute "AIRCOMOANY"? Is this a constant defined somewhere? Also make sure this isn't a spelling error causing you problems, because
`aircompany = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(AIRCOMOANY));` may be causing some problem.

```
flight = db.findFlightByNumber(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("number")));
```

You are using session.getAttribute("number") but I don't see any place where you set the session attribute "number".

If you just desire the flight number entered by a user

```
`<form action="controller" method="post">
    <option value ="number"><fmt:message key="number"/></option>
    <input type="text" name="search" value ="">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="command" value ="getFlights">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>`
```

Try something like:

```
`<form action="controller" method="post">
    <label for="num">Flight Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="num" name="number">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="command" value ="getFlights">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>`
```

And then in your controller instead of:

```
`String search = request.getParameter("search");
if ("number".equals(search)){
    System.out.println("fewfw");
    flight = db.findFlightByNumber(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("number")));
}`
```

Try:

```
`String number = request.getParameter("number");
if(number != null){
    System.out.println("fewfw");
    flight = db.findFlightByNumber(number);
}`
```

Goodluck hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I understood where my mistake was)